# Determining the error for the parameters of a customised layer using keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, layer, tf.keras, keras-layer

I have created a custom layer using which will be used to determine the parameters of my functional. This customised layer is my output layer as well. The code for creating this layer is

```
class layer(tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(layer, self).__init__( **kwargs)
    
    A_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    self.A = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=A_init(shape=(1,), dtype="float32"),
        trainable=True,
    )
    B_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    self.B = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=B_init(shape=(1,), dtype="float32"), trainable=True
    )
    C_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    self.C = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=C_init(shape=(1,), dtype="float32"), trainable=True
    )


def call(self, z):
    print(self.n)
    return self.A**2 /((B/(z+1))**(C/2))

def get_config(self):
    config = super(layer, self).get_config()
    return config
```

mylayer = layer()

I have been able to print the values of these parameters 'A', 'B' and 'C'. I want to print the errors in these parameters as well. Can I do that using Keras model?

Comment: Keras does not and never had this functionality.

Comment: Can it be done by customising the layers or in any other way? @Dr. Snoopy

Comment: No, you should first think of how these errors should be computed, you haven't specified that.

Comment: If I assume that the values of the parameters are sampled from a Gaussian, then an integration of $exp(-(d_i - f_i(\theta)))^2/(2 \sigma_i^2)$ over the parameter space will give me a certain value. E.g. if I integrate from $-\sigma $ to $\sigma $ it should give me $0.68$.